# Using smart pointers for dynamically allocated arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Based on "Item 16: Use the same form in corresponding uses of `new` and `delete`" of Scott Meyers' Effective C++, you should not put dynamically allocated arrays in `auto_ptr` (or `tr1::shared_ptr`) since `delete p` instead of `delete[] p` is called upon destruction (also see [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520844/using-auto-ptr-with-array)). But does this still holds for C++11< and more in particular for `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`, since I noticed in some open source code the use of `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`? And if the latter is correct, how could one distinguish between `new` and `new []` allocated data?

Comment: Use `std::vector` for arrays (of other than `bool` maybe, depends). It is the standard dynamically sized array in C++.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr and look at point (2) and it's notes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is specialized for array types in C++11 where as it is not for `std::shared_ptr`.  So `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` will call `delete []` but `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]>` will just call `delete` by default.

This behavior has changed though in C++17.  In C++17 `std::shared_ptr` has been specialized for array types and using `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]>` will call `delete []`.

`

Answer (score 2):

The latter is correct, `unique_ptr` works fine with arrays. It has template specialization for array types which invokes `delete[]`. Nevertheless, Scott Meyers in his Effective Modern C++ suggests to use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of smart pointers on arrays.

Comment: He also suggests using `boost::scoped_array` and `boost::shared_array` ;) Can you provide a link to the template specialization for array types?

Comment: @Matthias look at Richard Critten's comment, he provides link to cppreference. The template instantiation is in your libstdc++ code.